# Display React properties by Id

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, fetch

I have multiples projects and I can't show each one properties in each project page by its ID.
(Using Nodejs, Reactjs, MongoDB...)
it gives an error

> Cast to ObjectId failed for value ":id" at path "_id" for model "project"

and this console.log :

```
console.log('-----------PROJECTS byId-----------', projects);
```

gives me `undefined`

My routes:

```
const express = require('express'),
Projects = require('../models/projects.js'),
app = express.Router();
exports.render_projects_byId = (req, res) => {
let id = req.params.id;

Projects.findById(id).exec((err, projects) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('-----------PROJECTS byId-----------', projects);
    res.json(projects)
  });
};
```

My Project Page that will appear project properties by it's own ID

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

import './Project.css';



class Project extends Component {
    state = {
     title : '',
     typeOfProduction: ''
    };

componentDidMount() {

    fetch('/dashboard/projects/:id')
    .then(response => { return response.json()
        .then(projects => {
            console.log(projects);
            this.setState({
                title: this.state.title,
                typeOfProduction: this.state.typeOfProduction
            })      
        })
    }).catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
}

render() {
 console.log("This.state.projects " + this.state.projects);

    return (

        <div>
            <section className="Project container">
                  <h1>
                  {this.state.title} oi
                  </h1>
                  <h1>
                  {this.state.typeOfProduction} oi
                  </h1>
            </section>
        </div>
    );

    }
}

export default Project;
```

My Project models Schema:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var projectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

   title: String,
   typeOfProduction: String
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("Projects", projectSchema);
```

Answer (score 1):

`"CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ id: ':id' }" at path "_id" for model "project"`

You are sending an object but it is expecting a string. You should try `Projects.findById(id) ....`

Comment: I tried and had the same error but "'Cast to ObjectId failed for value ":id" at path "_id" for model "project"'
 and now it says on browser console.log "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input"

Comment: I am a bit confused. You are defining a `postSchema` and setting the name Model to `projects`, but when you try to access it you do so by `Projects` and not `projects`. Did you import your model `const projects = require('path/to/db/model/');`? Also, I think you are missing a paranthesis in your Project component that has line `.then(response => { return response.json()`

Comment: sorry, already edit that postSchema to projectSchema and projects to Projects.
I imported const Projects = require('mypath). Already edit my post

Comment: can you try this? https://gist.github.com/avocadoras/25d27714199af16f3578b9c7291a53d2

Comment: thank you so much! helped me a lot your answer and already found my problem :D

Answer (score 0):

## Found my problem

I wasn't accessing the object the right way and its ID on fetch.

```
    console.log("PROPS " + JSON.stringify(this.props));
```

> PROPS
>
> {"match":{"path":"/project/:id","url":"/project/5ba945d25589902362b54469","isExact":true,"params":{"id":"5ba945d25589902362b54469"}},"location":{"pathname":"/project/5ba945d25589902362b54469","search":"","hash":""},"history":{"length":50,"action":"PUSH","location":{"pathname":"/project/5ba945d25589902362b54469","search":"","hash":""}}}

Then I had to access to object params like this:

> ```
>  const { match: { params } } = this.props;
> ```

Then I knew that I was accessing to route project :id the wrong way

> //before
>
> fetch(`/dashboard/project/:id`)
>
> //after
>
> fetch(`/dashboard/project/${params.id}`)

---

```
class Project extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      project: {}
    };
}


componentDidMount() { 

console.log("PROPS " + JSON.stringify(this.props));

    const { match: { params } } = this.props;


    fetch(`/dashboard/project/${params.id}`)
    .then(response => {  return response.json()
    }).then(project => {
        this.setState({
            project: project
        })
    })
}

render() {

    return (

        <div>
            <section className="Project container">
                  <h1>
                  {this.state.project.title} oi
                  </h1>
                  <h1>
                  {this.state.project.typeOfProduction} oi
                  </h1>
            </section>
        </div>
    );

 }
}

export default Project;
```